# Individually set the segments of a 4 Digit Display (TM1637)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am trying to set the segments of the 4 Digit Display (TM1637) individually, to print an exclamation mark (uploaded an image of how it will look, the segments highlighted in orange are what I wish to be lit. Segments A to G are shown on each segment for easy reference [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4rRsg.jpg))

I have tried researching for this, what I want is not surfaced.
I'm also programming this using Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

This is well described in the documentation of the python lib of the [TM1673](https://github.com/depklyon/raspberrypi-tm1637)

Just give it as binary input

```
      A
     ---
  F |   | B   *
     -G-      H (on 2nd segment)
  E |   | C   *
     ---
      D

  HGFEDCBA
0b01101101 = 0x6D = 109 = show "5"
```

Set it like this:

```
import tm1637
tm = tm1637.TM1637(clk=5, dio=4)
# show "COOL"
tm.write([0b00111001, 0b00111111, 0b00111111, 0b00111000])
```

I leave it to you to find out the correct binary strings from your drawing and the definition above.
[image]

[EDIT]

You seem to struggel with building the binary codes. So let's see how to build the first digit, the letter `C`. Note that position `H` is the `:` right of the numbers, so you want that set for your pattern.

`ADEF` are on (1), `BCGH` are off (0)

```
0bHGFEDCBA
0b00111001
```

For the second and 3rd digit `AD` are 1 and `BCEFGH` are 0.
For the 4th digit `ABCDEF`are 1 and `GH` are 0

Comment: I have seen that before, but what I want to print are not normal characters such as C, O, O, L. Well, the first “digit” I want to print represents a “C” and the last “digit” a “0”. However the middle two “digits” are not. I’m not sure how to set them (middle two “digits”) . How does the 0b00111001 work? I tried relating that to the number of segments(7), but the binary numbers has 8.

Comment: also, i clearly said segments highlighted in orange. the second "digit" is not a "H".

Comment: @sillygoose95 I see you struggle with constructing the binary strings. I explained the instrunction in a bit more detail. Have a look if this helps.